# importing certificates into firefox trusted root CAs programmaticaly by javascript

Tags: javascript, security, firefox, ssl, webrtc

I'm developing a webrtc application with sipml5 in firefox.
firefox does not allow unsecure connection from secure origin.
I have created a self signed certificate for my Communication server Asterisk (Secure websocket serving sipml5). But every time i want to login to to asterisk from my sipml5 page i should open a tab, write "wss://myAsteriskURL:8088" to add a security exception for my asterisk websocket connection.

Can any body show me a way to programaticaly add my my "ca.cert" to Firefox's "TRUSTED ROOT Certificate Authorities" with javaxcript code?? if actually a way exists!

Thank you

Comment: I am pretty sure you cannot do that as it is a huge security risk. What if any site could do this? There would be no need for certificate authorities as people could force their own.

Comment: Thank you @BenjaminTrent. But I cannot have my certificate signed by those popular authorities (for some reason). you mean there's no way to do this unless I ask my users to add mine if they are interested?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I am saying

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not possible to *inject* your ca.cert inside browsers trusted root certificate authorities with js.
But I can tell you that I had exactly the same problem: users can't be asked to accept two times the same certificate to use a web page, and I solved in another way: using `mod_proxy_wstunnel` in Apache/2.4.20.
Now showing a single https server to provide web pages and sip signaling the user is required to accept just a single certificate.
Here is the relevant part of the config:

```
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_connect_module modules/mod_proxy_connect.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
LoadModule proxy_wstunnel_module modules/mod_proxy_wstunnel.so

<VirtualHost *:443>
DocumentRoot ...
ServerName clic2call.demo.sociale.it:443
ErrorLog ...
TransferLog ...
SSLEngine on
...
SSLProxyCheckPeerName off
SSLProxyEngine On
SSLProxyCheckPeerCN off
SSLProxyCheckPeerName off
SSLProxyCheckPeerExpire off
SSLProxyVerify none
ProxyPass /ws  wss://127.0.0.1:8088/ws retry=0
</VirtualHost>
```

I hope it can be useful to solve your problem.